# Changing an exposed filter to use check_plain() or filter_xss()

Tags: views, forms

I have a view with a search filter. I am using **Acunetix** scanner to scan for vulnerabilities, which reports me an issue about the search filter. How do I alter it to use `check_plain(filter_xss($string))` or `filter_xss(check_plain($string))` in view exposed forms (a block, in my case)?

Comment: I find it odd and hard to believe that views doesn't do this already... Perhaps somewhere behind the scenes, they are already doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a form alter in your custom module. ie :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
        $view = $form_state['view'];
        if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name' && $view->current_display == 'display_name') {
            // alter your exposed form here
            $form['yourdata_item'] = check_plain(filter_xss($string));
        }
    }
}
```